# Hide a table row if a cell inside contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I would like to be able to hide a table row, only if a cell inside the table contains the word Complimentary, on all pages in my website.

An example page is here: https://widac.com.au/event/widac-event/

this picture shows the part I was to be hidden from view:
[image]

if anyone can tell me how to do this - it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use Jquery's `:contains()` selector, see [here](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide table row based on content of table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060478/hide-table-row-based-on-content-of-table-cell)

Comment: How is this a "php" and "wordpress" question?

Comment: @Bec9999 would you like to hide only on specific page or on entire website. Please confirm. Is the text Complimentary will always found in table .

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tblId tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td')..each(function() {
       if (this.textContent.includes('Complimentary')) {
           $(this).parent().hide();
       }
    });
});
```

`#tblId` is id of that particular table and i iterate on tr and inside each of tr, i invoke each of td, i match the content and hide that particular tr

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(td) {
  if (td.textContent.includes('Complimentary')) {
    td.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

jQuery:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  if (this.textContent.includes('Complimentary')) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});
```

Although in your example site, `.tribe-tickets-form-row` has `display: block !important`, which overrides this. You could set `.opacity = 0`, although it would still be interactable. Or you could just straight up `.remove()` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".tribe-events-tickets tr").each( function (el) {
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            if (text.indexOf("Complimentary") !== -1 ) {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

This can help, but at first this CSS rule in your code should be modified:

```
   .tribe-tickets-form-row {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block !important;
   }
```

remove the '!important', it doesn't allow to hide elements.
I hope it'll help.